# FreeRadius rlm_ldap::ldap_groupcmp: ldap_get_values() failed

Tags: freeradius

I'm in the process of configuring freeRadius to our ldap server. I can authenticate from user perspective to radius client. But when radius is trying query about the  to ldap groups we are getting these below error

[ldap] performing search in uid=vchevakula@test.us,ou=users,dc=test,dc=us, with filter (objectclass=*)
rlm_ldap::ldap_groupcmp: ldap_get_values() failed  or if we are changing any in group membership filter we are getting implementation error

```
[ldap] ldap_release_conn: Release Id: 0
[files]     expand: (&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(UniqueMember=%{User-Name})) -> (&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(UniqueMember=vchevakula@test.us))
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Checking Id: 0
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Got Id: 0
  [ldap] performing search in dc=test,dc=us, with filter (&(cn=Dev-Nw)(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(UniqueMember=vchevakula@cstest.us)))
  [ldap] object not found
  [ldap] ldap_release_conn: Release Id: 0
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Checking Id: 0
  [ldap] ldap_get_conn: Got Id: 0
  [ldap] performing search in 
uid=vchevakula@cstest.us,ou=users,dc=test,dc=us, with filter (objectclass=*)
    rlm_ldap::ldap_groupcmp: ldap_get_values() failed
      [ldap] ldap_release_conn: Release Id: 0
```

users file in free radius

```
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "Dev-Nw"
DEFAULT Ldap-Group == "SRE"
        Reply-Message = "You are allowed"
```

modules/ldap in free radius

```
  groupname_attribute = cn
    groupmembership_filter = "(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(UniqueMember=%{User-Name}))"
        groupmembership_attribute = radiusGroupName
```

I tried changing the groupmembership filter but none of them worked until right now. I'm getting the same error that it couldn't figure out . Freeradius -X keeps failing on the finding groups

groupname_attribute = cn
        #groupmembership_filter = "(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(uniquemember=%{control:Ldap-UserDn}))"
    #groupmembership_filter = "(|(&(objectClass=GroupOfNames)(member=%{control:Ldap-UserDn}))(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(uniquemember=%{control:Ldap-UserDn})))"
    #groupmembership_filter = "(|(&(objectClass=GroupOfNames)(member=%{Ldap-UserDn}))(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(uniquemember=%{Ldap-UserDn})))"
    groupmembership_filter = "(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(UniqueMember=%{User-Name}))"
    groupmembership_attribute = radiusGroupName

ldap attributes from ldap server

```
dn: cn=SRE,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=us
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupofUniqueNames
cn: SRE
uniqueIdentifier: XXXXXXX
description: SRE Team
uniqueMember: uid=vchevakula@test.us,ou=users,dc=test,dc=us
uniqueMember: uid=nuser@test.us,ou=users,dc=test,dc=us
```

need some help in configuring ldap groups in freeradius

Comment: It's been several years since the 2.x series was supported by the FreeRADIUS project.  I would upgrade to v3.0.x and see if you still experience the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I have resolved my problem

By adding  this below line to my configuration in freeradius server /etc/freeradius/modules/ldap

```
groupmembership_filter = "(&(objectClass=GroupOfUniqueNames)(uniqueMember=%{control:Ldap-UserDn}))"
```